# Add new Dropdown Action to the Admin Product Page

Tags: shopify

In Shopify how can I add a new dropdown action to the admin product page?
Something similar to this: https://ibb.co/dxyika

I've looked at the API and I can't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called [app links.](https://help.shopify.com/partners/making-apps/app-admin-access) If you have created a public app then you can set up app links through [adjusting your app settings in the partners dashboard.](https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/api_clients)

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a way to add the links via an API call?

Comment: There isn't, sorry @AndréFerraz

Comment: Thank you very much Josh